# The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not ‘APPL’ or ‘FMWK’. Unable to validate your application. (-21017)

Tags: github-actions, bundle, info.plist

I'm trying to upload bundle to Appstore with Github Actions for an app with multiple targets (one per environment: internal, client and retail). I'm getting this error:

*** Error: Error uploading 'build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa'.
*** Error: Could not determine the package’s bundle ID. The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not ‘APPL’ or ‘FMWK’. Unable to validate your application. (-21017)
{
NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not determine the package\U2019s bundle ID. The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not \U2018APPL\U2019 or \U2018FMWK\U2019.";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to validate your application.";
}

I already have CFBundlePackageType with APPL. I also tried changing it to FMWK.
This is the content of my Info.plist inside the folder's corresponding target:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.myapp.internal</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.myapp.internal</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use Apple Music</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your camera for modifying your avatar picture.</string>
    <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use FaceID</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use location</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to save photos to your photo gallery</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like access to your photo gallery for uploading your avatar picture.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I'm using these commands to generate the bundle:

```
cd ios

    BUILD_NUMBER=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
    xcrun agvtool new-version -all ${BUILD_NUMBER}

    # creates an .xarchive file
    xcodebuild -workspace myapp.xcworkspace \
        -scheme myappinternal clean archive -configuration Internal \
        -archivePath ./build/Products/myapp.xcarchive \

    # converts the .xarchive file to .ipa by including the provisioning profile
    xcodebuild -exportArchive \
        -archivePath ./build/Products/myapp.xcarchive \
        -exportPath ./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa \
        -exportOptionsPlist exportOptionsInternal.plist

    # upload the .ipa to Apple Connect
    xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file ./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa \
        --username "$IOS_APP_STORE_CONNECT_USERNAME" --password "$IOS_APP_STORE_CONNECT_PASSWORD"
```

The content of the exportOptionsInternal.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.myapp.internal</key>
        <string>Github_Actions_Myapp_Internal</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I appreciate any help. I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm new to all of this and honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same issue here, also with Github actions. Do you also use fastlane by any chance?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem when my MacBook updated to XCode 14. Circle CI worked well (XCode 13.4.1 + Fastlane) with the same code.

Finally, it worked again after I removed the workaround `ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=true`

See more:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20741#issuecomment-1306967243

Answer (score 2):

Using Xcode14.2 and fastlane2.212.1, `remove ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=true` does not work as `ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD` has never been set before.

But explicitly set `ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=false` works.(In Fastfile,add `ENV['ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD'] = 'false'`) See  https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20910

Comment: This helped us resolve this use when using Ionic Appflow to build out cordova application.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Original poster did not mention fastlane, and all the answers are related to fastlane. So for anyone who is experiencing this problem, **while not using fastlane** (using command line interface), the problem in the original question is with the second command:

```
    xcodebuild -exportArchive \
        -archivePath ./build/Products/myapp.xcarchive \
        -exportPath ./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa \ <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        -exportOptionsPlist exportOptionsInternal.plist
```

**The export path should not include the name of the IPA file.** The name of the ipa file will be automatically generated from the `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`. So if you specify `./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa`, the IPA will actually be something like `./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa/My App.ipa`

Instead, provide the `-exportPath ./build/Products/IPA`.

And in `xcrun altool` ensure that you are referring to a correct name of the IPA. It may not be `./build/Products/IPA/myapp.ipa` as you expect, but `./build/Products/IPA/My App.ipa`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created my ipa file without fastlane, just terminal:

```
xcodebuild -workspace $PWD/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath $PWD/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist $PWD/ios/exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build/ios/iphoneos/IPA
```

and this is how i uploaded it:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f ./build/ios/iphoneos/IPA/myapp.ipa -t ios -u my@email.com -p kccx-hytm-adsf-asdf
```

the {product_name}.ipa file -f gets generated by the first command. The name depends on the  given product_name. The passwort -p is the application-specific password that can be generated in the apple developer portal.

Alternatively can the Transporter App be used to upload the app.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode14.1.0 and fastlane2.212.1

```js
ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=false
```

work's for me